# JAXB - add multiple @XmlElement

Tags: java, jaxb

I need the following XML structure for my dokument

```
<elem_one>
<elem_alpha>
<elem_beta>
<elem_gama>
<elem_two>
```

And in my case, I want the three elements in the middle grouped in a class, so that my java class looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class InsertOrUpdatePeriodicPaymentRequestXML {
   @XmlElement(name="elem_one")
   private Long elementOne;

   // what annotation can I use here?
   private Letters letters;

   @XmlElement(name="elem_two")
   private Long elementTwo;
}

// ====================

public Class Letters {       
   @XmlElement(name="elem_alpha")
   private Long elementAlpha;

   @XmlElement(name="elem_beta")
   private Long elementBeta;

   @XmlElement(name="elem_gama")
   private Long elementGama;    
}
```

Can you please help me with this? With the code above, I would have only two elements in my XML document:

```
<elem_one>
<elem_two>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MOXy as you JAXB (JSR-222) provider you can use our `@XmlPath` extension:

```
@XmlPath(".")
private Letters letters;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html